# About "WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I'm using JPA in Wildfly application.

If I use datasource from the application server with this persistence.xml all is fine

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="ds" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            .... some options
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

But if I'm trying to use it with in application DB connection properties I got "WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required" exception.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="ds" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaee_test_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>

            .... some options
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Why it works this way? What should I do to fix?

Comment: You should always use a managed connection pool unless you have very good reason not to. It's only a minor task to define the datasource in the server config rather than being baked into the app

Comment: I understand. But my question is about different thing)

Comment: Is the code running in both variants inside an application server?  Inside an app server you might get (indirectly) Transaction Magagement by the container. If you run it outside you have to do it programmatically.